# ¿Como puedo leer un dato en especifico en un archivo para mostrarlo en pantalla al usuario? C++

Tags: c++

realmente aun no sé mucho sobre la manipulación de archivos, incluso, me gustaría aprender mas sobre ellos, pero no consigo un sitio que hable de ellos a fondo porque siento que es un tema algo complejo, en este caso necesito crear una estructura que almacene unos datos, pero el problema viene cuando voy a crear una función para leer los datos, ya que no sé como especificarle al programa cuando es un dato "string" y cuando es un dato "int".

Este es el enunciado de lo que me están pidiendo hacer:

***3: Crear y cargar una estructura registros de N cantidad de datos que posea la siguiente
información: código artículo, descripción, cantidad en stock, , marca, y fecha,
opción 4: Mostrar todos los datos de la estructura, en la cual se muestre el
articulo con mayor cantidad en stock.***

Este seria el método que cree para crear dicha estructura y almacenar los datos:

```
void Programa::estructura(){
ofstream archivo;

cout<<"================================================="<<endl;
cout<<"=\tCrear y Cargar Estructura\t\t="<<endl;
cout<<"================================================="<<endl;
cout<<"= Digite la cantidad de articulos que desea\t="<<endl;
cout<<"= registrar. \t\t\t\t\t="<<endl;
cout<<"= \t\t\t\t\t\t="<<endl;
cout<<"= Nota: Se reemplazaran los articulos ya \t="<<endl;
cout<<"= existentes. \t\t\t\t\t="<<endl;
cout<<"================================================="<<endl;
cout<<"Digitar: "; cin>>articulos;
system("cls");

archivo.open("articulos.txt", ios::out); //Abriendo el archivo

if(archivo.fail()){
    cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo";
    exit(1);
}

//Datos dados por el usuario
for(int i=0;i<articulos;i++){
    cout<<"================================================="<<endl;
    cout<<"=\tCrear y Cargar Estructura\t\t="<<endl;
    cout<<"================================================="<<endl;
    cout<<"= Articulo Numero: "<<i+1<<"\t\t\t\t="<<endl;
    cout<<"================================================="<<endl;
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"= Codigo Articulo: "; cin.getline(datos[i].codigoArticulo,20,'\n');
    cout<<"= Descripcion: "; cin.getline(datos[i].descripcion,20,'\n');
    cout<<"= Cantidad Stock: "; cin>>datos[i].cantidadStock;
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"= Marca: "; cin.getline(datos[i].marca,20,'\n');
    cout<<"= Fecha (DD-MM-AA): "; cin.getline(datos[i].fecha,20,'\n');
    
    system("cls");
}

//Guardando en el archivo
for(int i=0;i<articulos;i++){
    archivo<<"================================================="<<endl;
    archivo<<"= Articulo Numero: "<<i+1<<"\t\t\t\t="<<endl;
    archivo<<"================================================="<<endl;
    archivo<<"= Codigo Articulo:"<<datos[i].codigoArticulo<<endl;
    archivo<<"= Descripcion: "<<datos[i].descripcion<<endl;
    archivo<<"= Cantidad Stock: "<<datos[i].cantidadStock<<endl;
    archivo<<"= Marca: "<<datos[i].marca<<endl;
    archivo<<"= Fecha: "<<datos[i].fecha<<endl;
    archivo<<"================================================="<<endl;
}

archivo.close(); //Cerrando el archivo
```

}

Y este es el método que cree para mostrar los datos en pantalla para que el usuario los vea, y también donde tengo la duda, ya que no sé una forma o de que manera puedo leer un dato en especifico para mostrarlo al usuario, en este caso quiero leer solamente los datos de "cantidad stock" para unos cálculos con el y así mostrar en pantalla solamente la información donde el articulo con la mayor cantidad de stock, junto con el resto de información correspondiente a ese mismo articulo:

```
void Programa::leerEstructura(){
ifstream archivo;
string lectura;
int mayor=0, i=0;

archivo.open("articulos.txt", ios::in); //Abriendo el archivo

if(archivo.fail()){
    cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo";
    exit(1);
}

cout<<"================================================="<<endl;
cout<<"=\t\tMostrar Estructura\t\t="<<endl;
cout<<"================================================="<<endl;
cout<<"=\tInformacion del archivo:\t\t="<<endl;

while(archivo>>datos[i].cantidadStock){
    i++;
    if(datos[i].cantidadStock>mayor){
        mayor=datos[i].cantidadStock;
    }
    cout<<"Mayor: "<<mayor;
}

archivo.close(); //Cerrando el Archivo
system("pause");
system("cls");
```

}

[image: Datos adentro del archivo y que uso para probar:]

Comment: Sería de mucha ayuda para nosotros que dieras un ejemplo del contenido del archivo y el resultado esperado luego de procesarlo.

Comment: ya re edite la pregunta con una imagen para que puedan entender mejor a lo que me refiero

Comment: ¿Cómo es el contenido del archivo? ¿Usas un struct?

Comment: si, uso un struct para almacenar todos los datos

Answer (score 0):

Mira un artículo:

```
==========================
= Articulo Numero: 1     =
==========================
= Codigo Articulo: 123
= Descripcion: artículo
= Cantidad Stock: 3
= Marca: marca
= Fecha: 22-22-22
==========================
```

Para mostrarlo se ve bien. Pero para procesarlo no es tan fácil. La complejidad depende de cómo lo guardes.

El procedimiento de lectura será similar y en el mismo orden que el de escritura. Con la diferencia que ahora necesitas ignorar ciertas partes del archivo.

Suponiendo que tu struct se llama **Articulo**, puedes hacerlo así:

```
void ignorar(ostream& os, char caracter){
    archivo.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), caracter);
}

// ...

Articulo articulo;

while (archivo){
    ignorar(archivo, ':');
    ignorar(archivo, ':');
    archivo >> articulo.codigoArticulo;
    ignorar(archivo, ':');
    archivo >> articulo.descripcion;
    ignorar(archivo, ':');
    archivo >> articulo.cantidadStock;
    ignorar(archivo, ':');
    archivo >> articulo.marca;
    ignorar(archivo, ':');
    archivo >> articulo.fecha;
    ignorar(archivo, '\n');

    // ...
}
```

Puedes ver que uso la función [`ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) para ignorar líneas enteras o hasta un `:` ya que luego de él se encuentra lo importante.

El primer parámetro es el máximo y el segundo es el caracter a encontrar.

Por cierto, podrías guardar la información directamente a `datos[i]` siempre y cuando no excedas la capacidad.

---

Te propongo algunas alternativas:

- La más fácil y eficiente, guardar el struct en binario. La desventaja es que los archivos generados por una computadora pueden no ser compatibles con otra.

  Para empezar, abre el archivo en modo binario.

  ```
  archivo.open(/* ... */, ios::binary);
  ```

  Para escribir usas la función [`write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) y para leer [`read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read). Cómo primer parámetro reciben un puntero donde se encuentran o van a guardar los datos y el tamaño en bytes.

  Por ejemplo:

  ```
  // Escribir y leer un entero
  int n = 5;
  archivo.write((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
  archivo.read((char*)&n, sizeof(n));

  // Un arreglo 
  int arreglo[10];
  archivo.write((char*)&n, sizeof(arreglo));
  archivo.read((char*)&n, sizeof(arreglo));
  ```
- Usar otro formato para guardar la información. Por ejemplo, csv que es versátil y muy usado. Te dejo la tarea de pensar como sería el código.

Comment: Leyendo todo, no comprendo muy aun como hacerlo, ya que la verdad aun no me he aprendido nada acerca de punteros (si es que los hay en tu ejemplo, lo digo por el "&" y el "*", entonces no entiendo muy bien que debería hacer, entiendo que al guardarlo de una forma que se vea bonito o bien estética, hará que sea mas complejo leerlo, pero sigo con la duda para leerlo, y otra cosa, con formato csv, quieres decir que le cambie el .txt, por .csv?????

Comment: y perdona si suena un poco fastidioso que no lo comprenda, pero llevo días buscando y buscando, y lo que encuentro sigue sin funcionar o de darme una idea clara de como hacerlo

Comment: @Snow ¿Entendiste la primera parte? Es lo más importante. Lo otro son alternativas y no tienes que hacerlo si no quieres. En cuanto a los punteros, `&` te da la dirección de memoria de una variable. Con `*` accedes al valor en una dirección de memoria, pudiendo leerlo o modificarlo. Yo solo me limito a lo primero ya que las funciones necesitan un puntero.

Comment: Sobre el archivo csv, lo normal es que su extensión sea csv.